# a pointer to function within a operator

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

for homework, I need to write a program in cpp with a class composed of an array of pointer to function and operators. I need to create an operator + so as when in the main, this would happen:

```
int main()
{
int SIZE = 5;
ptrF* arrPtrF = new ptrF[SIZE];
arrPtrF[0] = add;
arrPtrF[1] = sub;
arrPtrF[2] = mult;
arrPtrF[3] = div1;
arrPtrF[4] = pow;
Delegate D1(arrPtrF, SIZE)
cout<< D1[0](6, 7) + D1[0](1, 2)<<endl; 
}
```

the outcome is 15

I am finding difficulty with writing the operator+ ( which in this case need to take take a object parameter)

at first i tried this:

```
Delegate Delegate:: operator + (const Delegate& b)
{
Delegate tmp;

tmp.m_ptrF[i] = m_ptrF[i] + b.m_ptrF[i];

return tmp;
}
```

but it gave me an error about the i and b.m_ptrF->initialized i and something about an enum type.

then i tried this:

```
int Delegate:: operator + (const Delegate& b)
{
int tmp;
int i, x,y;

    tmp = m_ptrF[i](x, y) + b.m_ptrF[i](x, y);

return tmp;
}
```

but it gives me an error->initialized x,y,i knowing that i is index and x,y the parameters of the pointer to function.

what can i do to make it work?

Comment: what is HMWK ? Please include a [mcve] and the complete compiler error message

Comment: @Scheff maybe. Could also be [high-molecular-weight-kininogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-molecular-weight_kininogen)

Comment: What type is `ptrF`?

Comment: It's not clear at all what the purpose of the `operator+` is. I suspect that you have misunderstood something.

Comment: Could you please post the exact error message and the constructor for the Delegate class? It's also not clear where `i` is getting initialised. That may be your issue; it isn't.

Comment: @idclev HMWK short for homework

Comment: @molbdnilo ptrF is the name of my pointer to function defined by 
typedef int (*ptrF) (int, int);. All functions composing the array are int type functions that accept two parameters. The purpose of the operator+ is to add up two specific terms from an object's array of pointer to functions.

Comment: @molbdnilo  In the program it must be shown as (example of object is Delegate D1): D1[0](6,7)+D1[1](3,1) //using an operator[], the object will extract its terms in the place 0 of the array which is "add". But since it is a pointer to function, I must also insert two values to initiate it. same thing for D1[1](3,1). the operator+ must take in both results and sum it up.

Comment: @NessyaNakache So how is this operator+ different from a regular integer addition?

Comment: @OMGtechy here is the constructor: Delegate::Delegate(ptrF* ptr, int size)
{
 m_size = size;
 m_ptrF = new ptrF[size];
 for (int i = 0; i < size;i++, ptr++)
 {
  m_ptrF[i] = *ptr;
 }

}

Comment: @john because it is part of the homework requirements and I tried withou the operator+ and it didn't work

Comment: @NessyaNakache That's no answer,  it didn't work without operator+, but now it's not working with operator+. Let me put the question a different way, what type do you think `D1[0](6,7)` is? If I just wrote `cout << D1[0](6,7) << endl` what would I see?

Comment: `D1[0]` requires an overload of `operator[]`, not `operator+`. You must have misunderstood something about the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `D1[0](6, 7)` is supposed to perform `6 + 7` returning an `int` and `D1[0](1, 2)` is supposed to perform `1 + 2` also returning an `int`. So the addition in `D1[0](6, 7) + D1[0](1, 2)` is just a regular `int` addition.

So in other words you are not supposed to be overloading `Delegate::operator+` instead you are supposed to writing something like this

```
XXX Delegate::operator[](int i) const
{
    ...
}
```

where `XXX` is a function like type that will perform the addition on the later parameters.

So `XXX` will be something like

```
class XXX
{
public:
    int operator()(int x, int y) const
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```

But `XXX` will have to perform addition, or substraction or whatever, as appropriate.

So the expression `D1[0](6, 7)` becomes `temp(6,7)` where temp is an object of the `XXX` type above.

At least that's my best interpretation. It's clear that you have misunderstood your requirements.